# For if in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out the difference in using 'for' in this task.

```
def longest_consec(strarr, k):

    for i in range(0,len(strarr)):

        if len(strarr) > 0 and k >= 0 and k <= len(strarr):
            join = list(map(''.join, [strarr[i:k+i]]))
            longest = max(join, key=len)
            return longest
        
    else:
        return('')
```

```
def longest_consec(strarr, k):
    
    if len(strarr) > 0 and k >= 0 and k <= len(strarr):
       join = list(map(''.join, [strarr[i:i+k] for i in range(0, len(strarr))]))
       longest = max(join, key=len)
       return longest 
        
    else:
        return('')
```

Only 2nd one works. Why 'for' with 'i' index can't stay outside of map(), just like in the 1st one?

The order:

> You are given an array(list) strarr of strings and an integer k. Your
> task is to return the first longest string consisting of k consecutive
> strings taken in the array.
>
> Example:
>
> strarr = ["tree", "foling", "trashy", "blue", "abcdef", "uvwxyz"], k =
> 2
>
> Two strings are the longest: "folingtrashy" and "abcdefuvwxyz". The
> first that came is "folingtrashy" so  longest_consec(strarr, 2) should
> return "folingtrashy".

Comment: The list comprehension is a loop, so you finished a full loop before you returned. What you're doing in the other loop is like "which is the biggest in [1, 2, 3]" and shouting "1, FINAL ANSWER!!!" because it is the biggest so far, before hearing about 2 or 3.

Comment: `join = ["".join(strarr[i:i+k]) for i in range(len(strarr))]` does the same as what you do but is a tad bit easier to follow. I would also recommend flipping the test around to return fast as it also makes the code easier in my opinion.

Comment: `len(strarr) > 0` is unnecessary in the first version. If the length were 0, the range would be empty and you'd never get into the loop.

Comment: Also, on an unrelated note, look up sliding_window in more-itertools, or the itertools recipes documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first part you are iterating over each index value, and then applying check condition and only taking first k element for joining them together. also there is return inside the loop, beacuse of this once you got the first result ie join value, your code immediately return its.

to solve this.

- you need to store the value of newly joined string in some object
- compare that value to newly created string object in next iteration of for loop
- once all looping is done, then return the string

Adding below code, which is one of way to solve this problem

```
def longest_consec(strarr, k):
    string = ''
    for i in range(0, len(strarr)):
        if len(strarr) > 0 and k >= 0 and k <= len(strarr):
            new_string= ''.join(strarr[i:k + i])
            string = string if len(string) >= len(new_string) else new_string
    return string
```